# JavaScript selected text entirely within node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking into text selection and ranges in JavaScript.

I need to get any nodes that surround the selected text exactly, for example:

```
<div>this is <span>some simple</span> text</div>
```

When the user selects the words 'some simple' i need to know that it sits entirely within the node .
Yet if they select just 'some' then this is not entirely within the node  as the word 'simple' is NOT selected.

The end requirement is to be able to amend the class on the node only if the whole text within the node is selected.

jquery is also viable. thanks

To add some more context to this, when a user selects some text we add some sytling to it, let's say 'bold'. the user can edit the text in the parent div as often as they wish so each edit could add a new span enclosing the selected text. We could end up with something like this:

```
<div><span class="text-bold">Hi</span>, <span class="text-red">this <span class="text-italic">is</span></span> a sample text item</div>
```

So the spans can come and go dependant on what the user wants.

Comment: Try the Rangy library: https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki

Comment: Hi, Thanks Rory but i was hoping to avoid more plugins, ideally a pure javascript solution is preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies, it allowed me to cobble together my solution:

```
 function applyTextFormatClass(className) {
        var selection = getSelected();
        var parent = selection.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer; //see comment and link below
        if (parent.nodeType !== 1) {
            parent = parent.parentNode; //we want the parent node
        }
        var tagText = parent.innerText;
        var selectText = selection.toString();

        if (tagText.length !== selectText.length) {
            addNodeAroundSelectedText(selection, className); //create new node
        } else {
            addClass(parent, className); //add class to existing node
        }
    }
```

commonAncestorContainer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/commonAncestorContainer

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to get the `DOM` each time. So you can set id to your `HTML Element Objects` and get the value from them. For example:

```
 <span id="f_span">some simple</span>

<script>
     var x = document.getElementById("f_span");
</script>
```

Then you can check if `x` value equals with the value that user had selected.

Comment: hi, thanks, nice suggestion but would'n't work if the there were 2 similar words that are enclosed by seperate tags

Comment: I am sorry but i can't understand why it wouldn't work? You are getting the value from the element object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to get the selected text every x second. With the joined function you can get the selected text.

For the selection of user :

```
function getSelected() {
    if(window.getSelection) { return window.getSelection(); }
    else if(document.getSelection) { return document.getSelection(); }
    else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
        if(selection.text) { return selection.text; }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It return an object that give you the offset of the selection. If `result.anchorOffset = 0` and `result.focusOffset = result.anchorNode.length` (if it start at the begining of the node and it have the length of the whole node), then the user selected all your node.